# firefox add-on sdk: make panel to stay visible

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm trying to build a Firefox add-on based on their SDK and I wanna use [panel](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/packages/addon-kit/panel.html) for this. The panel is connected to a [widget](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/packages/addon-kit/widget.html), so every time I click on the widget icon the panel shows up. 
My problem is that I want the panel to stay visible even if I click on an area outside the panel and to be able to close only based on a certain situations.
Can this be achieved, or the panel API doesn't support this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It can't be achieved through the SDK API. However, you could actually "hack" the panel in order to be persistent, the problem is that you will face with other issue – basically won't go away, and other small stuff.

You can get additional details on Bugzilla if you're interested: [Add a "isPersistent" attribute for panels](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=595040). Notice that the bug is a WONTFIX, but it will give you an idea about the issue you could face. Also, there are some new widgets that will coming in the future, that could mitigate the needs to have the panel "persistent" (they're mentioned and linked in the bug above).

Answer (score 1):

This is the offical sdk method of doing it:

```
let myPanel = Panel({.....})

let { getActiveView }=require("sdk/view/core");
getActiveView(myPanel).setAttribute("noautohide", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Floating panels are not supported by the SDK